# Is there a way to break out of a flex container for a single item

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to follow some advice i've seen regarding not using margins for spacing and instead to use a flex container with column direction and the gap property. It's much nicer, except I can't work out how to break out of the container when needed for a background color on single flex items.

https://codepen.io/Xe11o/pen/VwVOpPP

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 1130px;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  gap: 50px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  font-size: 50px;
}

footer {
  font-size: 25px;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='container'>
      <header>
        <span>title text</span>
        <nav>
          <button>button link 1</button>
          <button>button link 2</button
        </nav>
      </header>
      <section>main content</section>
      <footer>
        Footer content.
        <br />
        How do i get this background color to stretch beyond the flex container to the edge of the screen?
        <br />
        I can remove the max-width+margin from the container and apply them instead to the children (header, section), then maybe do an align-items on the container, but then I can't get the header to look like it does right now.
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you can create a new relatively positioned view stack by putting the footer contents into a container with CSS position property set to `absolute` or `relative`. This is what I would call "breaking out"

Comment: Hmm there were some useful replies here a few minutes ago, from more than one person, that now seem to have been deleted. First time using this site (for posting a question) but it seems a bit borked.

Comment: @rizingfit Comments may be deleted at any time by a moderator, by the comment author, or by enough user flags by other non-moderator users--they are 'ephemeral' here on Stack Overflow. If you think a comment is so useful that its contents should stick around, take a screenshot or copy the contents into the body of an answer or question (where appropriate); that's the only way to ensure a comment's contents will live on. Most likely the authors of the comments (or a moderator) deemed the contents no longer needed (possibly after an edit to the question) and removed them.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution for stretching your `<footer>` container to the edge of the screen is to apply a `width: 100vw;` to let the `<footer>` fill the whole screen horizontally and an `align-self: center;` to position the element accordingly in the center of the screen so you prevent any overflow issues.

P.S. I adjusted the `max-width` of `.container` so one can see that the layout of the header and main content doesn't change in the snippet.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  gap: 50px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  font-size: 50px;
}

footer {
  font-size: 25px;
  background: lightgray;
  width: 100vw;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='container'>
      <header>
        <span>title text</span>
        <nav>
          <button>button link 1</button>
          <button>button link 2</button
        </nav>
      </header>
      <section>main content</section>
      <footer>
        Footer content.
        <br />
        How do i get this background color to stretch beyond the flex container to the edge of the screen?
        <br />
        I can remove the max-width+margin from the container and apply them instead to the children (header, section), then maybe do an align-items on the container, but then I can't get the header to look like it does right now.
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The footer is restrained by the max-width of the container. It may be possible to break out of this but I think it would seem more sensible to remove this restriction to begin with.

In the example below, I've moved the max-width so that it applies to just the header and sections, and then the footer can expand to the edge of the page. (I've removed the margins on the body just to demonstrate that it goes right to the edge). You mentioned that doing this did not give you the desired header but I think it looks the same as in your example if you set the header width to 100%.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 50px;
}

header, section {
  max-width: 1130px;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  font-size: 50px;
}

footer {
  font-size: 25px;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='container'>
      <header>
        <span>title text</span>
        <nav>
          <button>button link 1</button>
          <button>button link 2</button
        </nav>
      </header>
      <section>main content</section>
      <footer>
        Footer content.
        <br />
        How do i get this background color to stretch beyond the flex container to the edge of the screen?
        <br />
        I can remove the max-width+margin from the container and apply them instead to the children (header, section), then maybe do an align-items on the container, but then I can't get the header to look like it does right now.
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The thing with this is, while I used the footer as an example, there are various <section> elements throughout the main content of the page which also to break out like the footer

Comment: You could change the CSS to apply only to certain sections. E.g. add a class to the sections you want/don't want to "break out".

Answer (score 0):

Use negative `margin` value and positive :-) `padding` value:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 1130px;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  gap: 50px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  font-size: 50px;
}

footer {
  font-size: 25px;
  background: lightgray;
  margin: -25px -1000vw; /* ⇐ */
  padding: 25px 1000vw; /* ⇐ */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <span>title text</span>
    <nav>
     <button>button link 1</button>
     <button>button link 2</button>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section>main content</section>
  <footer>
    Footer content.
    <br />
    How do i get this background color to stretch beyond the flex container to the edge of the screen?
    <br />
    I can remove the max-width+margin from the container and apply them instead to the children (header, section), then maybe do an align-items on the container, but then I can't get the header to look like it does right now.
  </footer>
</div>
```